# how can valgrind only detect memory leak problems, without Illegal read, uninitialised values, etc

Tags: c

I use this to test my example, but I only care about leak problems, how can I only detect memory leak problems, without Illegal read, uninitialised values, etc? Does valgrind support?

```
valgrind -s --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --error-exitcode=1 --errors-for-leak-kinds=definite --show-leak-kinds=definite --undef-value-errors=no my_example
```

I have read the manual of valgrind, but found no option to deal with it

Comment: You really should care about all those other issues...

Comment: Can you show a [mre] for which valgrind reports more than memory leaks? It'll be easier to verify answers that way.

Comment: It might be possible to write a suppression.  But as Shawn says, that's really not something you should want to do.

Comment: Also, uninitialized values is one way to *cause* memory leaks `if (uninitialized_bool) free(x);`.

Comment: we should solve all the problems detected, if time permits. Thanks all of you!